How to change the color of the value attribute displayed in the center of the MUI Gauge chart component
I want to use the material UI gauge but with a custom color for the value attribute displayed at the center. In this case the 60 displayed at the center of the image provided.
This is source code for the component:
<Gauge width={100} height={100} value={60} />

I've tried reading through the documentation to find a specific attribute that controls that but cant seem to find it.
Here's a link to the documentation. and a screenshot of mui gauge component: .

According to their documentation example, you can use a selector to select the corresponding element. After inspecting the element structure, you can use & .${gaugeClasses.valueText} text to select the text.
import * as React from 'react';
import { Gauge, gaugeClasses } from '@mui/x-charts/Gauge'; // <-- import gaugeClasses 

const settings = {
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  value: 60,
};

export default function ArcDesign() {
  return (
    <Gauge
      {...settings}
      sx={(theme) => ({
        [`& .${gaugeClasses.valueText}`]: {
          fontSize: 40,
        },
        [`& .${gaugeClasses.valueText} text`]: {
          fill: "#3b82f6" // <-- change text color
        },
      })}
    />
  );
}


Worked liked a charm. Thank you so much.
